# How to resolve "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5001: Connection refused" in crontab?

Tags: docker, curl, cron, connection-refused, failed-to-connect

I'm trying to get some json data from my API. My API is running in docker container. When I want to see this data, I just go to the http://localhost:5001/v1/executions endpoint and I can view my data as shown in the image below:

[This is my API's end point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwoZG.png)

But send a request from a crontab file to this end point, I get some errors. You can see the contents of the crontab file from the image below.

```
* * * * * curl -X GET -d '{"message":}' http:// 127.0.0.1:5001/v1/machines >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

[This is the content of the crontab file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLibG.png)

When I run my containers and this cron I get "Connection refused" error. You can see the error as shown in the image below.

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mEM3.png)

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Try this default docker IP:  172.17.0.1

Answer (score 2):

You have to use internal docker ip instead of localhost in your curl command.
Try to use `docker inspect <container-id>` command to find the ip address of your local network.